# Handling a promise in a return function

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am trying to `console.log` the `blockNumber` that my transaction was confirmed in with the following code:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction(
    {from:account3, to: account2, value: web3.utils.toWei('1','ether')}
).then(function(receipt) {console.log(receipt.blockNumber)}
```

Node.js then sends me the following UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

> (node:11957) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 9)
>
> { error:
>      Error: Timeout exceeded during the transaction confirmation process. Be aware the transaction could still get confirmed!
>          at _callee2$ (/Users/julianmartinez/node_modules/web3-core-method/dist/web3-core-method.cjs.js:434:36)
>          at tryCatch (/Users/julianmartinez/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
>          at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/julianmartinez/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
>          at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/julianmartinez/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
>          at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/julianmartinez/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
>          at _next (/Users/julianmartinez/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
>          at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5),

At the same time that I receive the previous error, I also receive the transaction receipt, but it does not console.log the block number.

Any idea about what is going on?

Comment: Which version of `web3` do you use?

Comment: web3 version 1.0.0-beta.55

Comment: I'd suggest to try with web3 v1.2 (which is 1.0.0-beta.37), new versions have odd bugs.

Comment: I ended up doing this. This helped out a lot. Thank you for the info.